# How to iterate objects in parent/child hierarchy without redundant lists?

Tags: delphi, hierarchy, tobjectlist

I have an object something like this...

```
type
  TMyObject = class(TObject)
  private
    FParent: TMyObject;
    FChildren: TObjectList<TMyObject>;
    function GetChildren(const Index: Integer): TMyObject;
  public
    constructor Create(AParent: TMyObject);
    destructor Destroy; override;
    function AddChild: TMyObject;
    procedure DeleteChild(const Index: Integer);
    function ChildCount: Integer;
    property Children[const Index: Integer]: TMyObject read GetChildren; default;
  end;
```

(There's much more but this is the fundamental idea)

This allows a simple parent/child relationship between objects, a hierarchy. One is the root, which contains a hierarchy of more.

All this is fine, except I also need to iterate a complete list of all these objects, regardless of hierarchy.

```
var
  Node: TMyObject;
for X := 0 to AllNodes.Count-1 do begin
  Node := AllNodes[X];
  //Do something with `Node`... 

end;
```

Naturally, I could just create an object list and maintain both at the same time...

```
FAllObjects: TObjectList<TMyObject>;
```

However, this is redundant. Every instance of `TMyObject` would have to be added/deleted to each structure at the same time. I'd like to get rid of requiring one master list, and only use the hierarchy objects. But I don't know how I could iterate all the objects without following the recursive hierarchy. For example, something as simple as getting a total count of all these items.

How can I maintain such an object hierarchy (which I can iterate all items in one single loop) **without** having to maintain two separate redundant structures?

For example, the `TTreeView.Items` has the behavior I'd like. You can use `Items.Count` and `Items[Index]` to iterate *all* items, or you can recursively iterate the tree hierarchy.

Comment: No sure I follow.  If you do f.i. a depth-first recursive traversal of a parent-child hierarchy, you don't need any separate explicit list at all - the "list" is the nodes which have been called in the recursion.  Any textbook "walk tree" traversal routine should illustrate what I mean.

Comment: @MartynA So are you suggesting, keep an internal track of a virtual "count" and "index" as I recursively step through?

Comment: I'm not suggesting anything really, except perhaps that the reliance in Delphi's generics collections on lists seems to create problems where none needs exist.  Consider a  traditional (pre-generics) binary tree:  you can recursively call this without the need for any kind of list at all, just the pointers to a node's child nodes.  And you don't need to store a "count" anywhere at all.

Comment: @MartynA Not sure I'm following. Refer to sample `for` loop I just added to my question. How would such an iteration work without knowing the `Count`? I'd hate to have to do a full recursive loop every time I want to get a `Count`.

Comment: "*For example, the `TListView.Items` has the behavior I'd like*" - a `TListView` does not represent a tree of objects. `TTreeView` does, and it even provides linear indexed access to all of the nodes, by iterating the nodes in order from top to bottom. It also provides an `Enumerator` to avoid the pitfall of havig to count the nodes ahead of time. Consider implementing a custom `Enumerator` for your own list.

Comment: @Remy Thanks, fixed. That's what I meant.

Comment: @JerryDodge: look at the implementation of `TTreeNodes` in `Vcl.ComCtrls.pas`.  `TTreeNodes.GetCount()` is easy, it just calls `TreeView_GetCount()` in the Win32 API, since the TreeView control knows now many nodes it has. That is easy to keep track of in your own list using a variable. But indexed access requires iterating the tree (which is what `TTreeNodes.GetNodeFromIndex()` does), and you don't want to do that in a loop. So an Enuemrator is best.

Comment: @Remy I am, and where it reads `Count` it appears to be calling `TreeView_GetCount` which is in turn sending some Windows message. Not a very useful reference for what I'm seeking.

Comment: @JerryDodge: [`TreeView_GetCount()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773815.aspx) is a Win32 API macro that sends a [`TVM_GETCOUNT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773572.aspx) message to the TreeView's `HWND`.

Comment: @Remy Indeed, but I'm not working with a tree view. That's my point :-)

Comment: @JerryDodge: My point is, your own list can use a variable to keep track of how many nodes are in the list, and just update that variable whenever a node is added or removed. That allows you to implement a `Count` very easily. But looping through a tree-like list using indexes is inefficient. You should implement an `Enumerator` instead, and then you can use a `for..in` loop instead of a `for..to` loop. See [Iteration Over Containers Using For Statements](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Enumerator#Iteration_Over_Containers_Using_For_statements) for how to implement an Enumerator.

Comment: You can not iterate hierarchy in one single loop cause its not a linearly ordered set.Linear order means that for each object there is only one parent and only one child, so u need some form of the List.

Comment: @Remy That's where MartynA was confusing me, by saying I have no need to keep track of `Count` at all. Clearly I do, for efficiency reasons. Doing a recursive loop every time I want a count is severe overkill.

Comment: @JerryDodge: you can't use a single traditional `for..to` loop to iterate an entire tree hierarchy, unless you first copy the nodes to a linear list, such as an array. So keeping track of the total count of nodes won't help you since you can't index to a specific node without first iterating through the previous nodes. Typically you would use a recursive iteration instead, where you loop through a given node's children and its children and so on until there are no more children, then you move on to that node's next sibling and iterate its children, and then the next sibling, and so on.

Comment: @JerryDodge: if you implement an enumerator (I have posted an answer now to demonstrate), you get the best of both worlds - a top-level `for..in` loop that acts like a linear loop without knowing any count, and is internally iterating through node children and siblings until there is nothing left to iterate.

Comment: @Remy What about caching indices every time a node is added, deleted, or moved? I see a tree node accomplishes such with its function `TTreeNode.GetIndex`, which basically just steps backwards and increments the result. Would the enumerator eliminate the need for either of those? **EDIT** Indeed, iterating without count or indices might actually be more efficient...

Comment: @JerryDodge: You can implement indexes if you want, but it is still not going to help you iterate through your list efficiently. Using a `while` loop that only cares whether a next node is available or not is all you need. And an enumerator does that for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a standard `TTreeView`, the best way to iterate through all of its nodes in a "linear" fashion from top to bottom is to utilize the [`TTreeNode.GetNext()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TTreeNode.GetNext) method in a `while` loop, eg:

```
var
  Node: TTreeNode;

Node := TreeView.GetFirstNode;
while Node <> nil do
begin
  //Do something with Node... 
  Node := Node.GetNext;
end;
```

In your custom node list, you can implement a similar iteration by implementing an Enumerator that can be used with a `for..in` loop, which was introduced in Delphi 2007.  See Embarcadero's documentation for more details:

[Declarations and Statements (Delphi): Iteration Over Containers Using For statements](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Enumerator#Iteration_Over_Containers_Using_For_statements)

For example:

```
type
  TMyObject = class(TObject)
  private
    FParent: TMyObject;
    FChildren: TObjectList<TMyObject>;
  public
    constructor Create(AParent: TMyObject);
    destructor Destroy; override;
    function PreviousSibling: TMyObject;
    function NextSibling: TMyObject;
    function FirstChild: TMyObject;
    property Parent: TMyObject read FParent;
  end;

function TMyObject.PreviousSibling: TMyObject;
var
  Index: Integer;
begin
  Result := nil;
  if FParent <> nil then
  begin
    Index := FParent.FChildren.IndexOf(Self);
    if Index > 0 then
      Result := FParent.FChildren[Index-1];
  end;
end;

function TMyObject.NextSibling: TMyObject;
var
  Index: Integer;
begin
  Result := nil;
  if FParent <> nil then
  begin
    Index := FParent.FChildren.IndexOf(Self);
    if (Index >= 0) and (Index < (FParent.FChildren.Count-1)) then
      Result := FParent.FChildren[Index+1];
  end;
end;

function TMyObject.FirstChild: TMyObject;
begin
  if FChildren.Count > 0 then
    Result := FChildren.First
  else
    Result := nil;
end;
```

```
type
  TMyListEnumerator = class
  private
    FList: TMyList;
    FCurrent: TMyObject;
  public
    constructor Create(AList : TMyList);
    function MoveNext: Boolean;
    property Current: TMyObject read FCurrent;
  end;

  TMyList = class
  private
    FRoot: TMyObject;
  public
    function GetEnumerator: TMyListEnumerator;
  end; 

constructor TMyListEnumerator.Create(AList: TMyList);
begin
  inherited Create;
  FList := AList;
  FCurrent := nil;
end;

function TMyListEnumerator.MoveNext: Boolean;
var
  LObject, LParent: TMyObject;
begin
  if FCurrent = nil then begin
    FCurrent := FList.FRoot;
  end else
  begin
    LObject := FCurrent.FirstChild;
    if LObject = nil then
      LObject := FCurrent.NextSibling;
    LParent := FCurrent;
    while (LObject = nil) and (LParent <> nil) do
    begin
      LParent := LParent.Parent;
      LObject := LParent.NextSibling;
    end;
    FCurrent := LObject;
  end;
  Result := FCurrent <> nil;
end;

function TMyList.GetEnumerator: TMyListEnumerator;
begin
  Result := TMyListEnumerator.Create(Self);
end;
```

```
var
  MyList: TMyList;
  Node: TMyObject;

// populate MyList as needed...

for Node in MyList do
begin
  //Do something with Node... 
end;
```

Behind the scenes, the compiler will generate code similar to the following:

```
var
  MyList: TMyList;
  Node: TMyObject;
  Enum: TMyListEnumerator;

// populate MyList as needed...

Enum := MyList.GetEnumerator;
try
  while Enum.MoveNext do
  begin
    Node := Enum.Current;
    //Do something with Node... 
  end;
finally
  Enum.Free;
end;
```

If you are using Delphi 2006 or earlier, `for..in` is not available, so you will have to use the above `while` loop explicitly instead.

Comment: All that Next, Previous, First is absolutely not necessary -  see my answer. Especially since that IndexOf usage is making that thing completely ineffective.

Comment: @StefanGlienke if `TMyObject`/`TMyList` were implemented as a true double-linked list, use of `TObjectList` would disappear, and the `NextSibling`/`PreviousSibling`/`FirstChild` values would be simple pointers, no lookups needed at all. That would make adds, removals, and traversals much more efficient.

Comment: Agreed but that was not the question.

Comment: I kept getting an Access Violation at the end of the loop, trying to call `NextSibling` for a `nil` object. I modified `MoveNext` accordingly...  `if LParent <> nil then
          LObject := LParent.NextSibling
        else
          LObject:= nil;` Also when list is empty, so I check `if FRoot.Count > 0` or of the such first.

Answer (score 4):

I would solve this in a functional way without any need to modify (*) the structure/classes you want to traverse.

What you need is the root items and a function to get an items childs.

(*) Regarding your `TMyObject` class it would need to expose the Childs somehow (I would do that by putting a `property Childs: TEnumerable<TMyObject>` in order to make them read only.

Here is how you can pre-order traverse basically any non-polymorph hierarchy:

```
unit HierarchyEnumerator;

interface

uses
  Generics.Collections,
  SysUtils;

type
  THierarchyEnumerable<T> = record
  private
    fItems: TEnumerable<T>;
    fChildSelector: TFunc<T, TEnumerable<T>>;

    type
      TEnumerator = class
      private
        fStack: TStack<TEnumerator<T>>;
        fChildSelector: TFunc<T, TEnumerable<T>>;
        fCurrent: T;
      public
        constructor Create(const items: TEnumerable<T>; const childSelector: TFunc<T, TEnumerable<T>>);
        destructor Destroy; override;
        function MoveNext: Boolean;
        property Current: T read fCurrent;
      end;
  public
    constructor Create(const items: TEnumerable<T>; const childSelector: TFunc<T, TEnumerable<T>>);
    function GetEnumerator: TEnumerator;
  end;

implementation

{ THierarchyEnumerable<T> }

constructor THierarchyEnumerable<T>.Create(const items: TEnumerable<T>;
  const childSelector: TFunc<T, TEnumerable<T>>);
begin
  fItems := items;
  fChildSelector := childSelector;
end;

function THierarchyEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator: TEnumerator;
begin
  Result := TEnumerator.Create(fitems, fChildSelector);
end;

{ THierarchyEnumerable<T>.TEnumerator }

constructor THierarchyEnumerable<T>.TEnumerator.Create(const items: TEnumerable<T>;
  const childSelector: TFunc<T, TEnumerable<T>>);
var
  item: T;
begin
  inherited Create;
  fStack := TStack<TEnumerator<T>>.Create;
  fStack.Push(items.GetEnumerator);
  fChildSelector := childSelector;
end;

destructor THierarchyEnumerable<T>.TEnumerator.Destroy;
begin
  fStack.Free;
  inherited;
end;

function THierarchyEnumerable<T>.TEnumerator.MoveNext: Boolean;
var
  e: TEnumerator<T>;
begin
  while fStack.Count > 0 do
  begin
    e := fStack.Pop;
    if e.MoveNext then
    begin
      fStack.Push(e);
      fCurrent := e.Current;
      fStack.Push(fChildSelector(fCurrent).GetEnumerator);
      Exit(True);
    end
    else
      e.Free;
  end;

  Result := False;
end;

end.
```

Using would look like this:

```
for o in THierarchyEnumerable<TMyObject>.Create(list,
  function(item: TMyObject): TEnumerable<TMyObject>
  begin
    Result := item.Children;
  end) do
  ...
```

Comment: Is this code leaking all of the `TEnumerator<T>` objects? `TEnumerator<T>` is a class, not an interface. `TStack` does not take ownership of the objects, and they are not being used in `for..in` loops where the compiler would have freed them automatically, so dont they need to be freed manually after being popped from the stack and `e.MoveNext` returns false?